# Regex to count non nested </p> tags

Tags: php, regex

The function below does pretty much what it says. It inserts a string of html into the content just after the 2nd paragraph tag it finds.

I need to alter it a bit so that it only counts paragraph tags that are not inside other tags. In other words, only top level paragraph tags.

Any way to do it with regex?

```
function my_html_insert($content){
    $InsertAfterParagraph = 2;

    if(substr_count(strtolower($content), '</p>') < $InsertAfterParagraph )
    {
        return $content .= myFunction($my_insert=1);
    }
    else
    {
        $replaced_content = preg_replace_callback('#(<p[\s>].*?</p>\n)#s', 'my_p_callback', $content);
    }
    return $replaced_content;
}


function my_p_callback($matches)
{
    static $count = 0;
    $ret = $matches[1];
    $pCount = get_option('my_p_count');

    if (++$count == $pCount){
        $ret .= myFunction($my_insert=1);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Why not parse the HTML?

Comment: regex seems simpler/faster (if its possible to do)

Comment: That's almost never the case. Regex isn't powerful enough to parse arbitrary HTML.

Comment: That's why I'm not asking it to parse. Just count.

Comment: Correct counting means to parse correctly: the above regex would happily fail on HTML comments, and for missing `</p>`, which is optional. However, most regex engines *are* powerful enough to match any right-recursive context free grammar (see `(?(DEFINE)(?<rule>pattern))` in PCRE or Perl). It's just not practical or easy to do *correctly*. That's why using a ready-made parser is the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd still parse it, as it's cleaner and easier to maintain:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Test 1</p>
            <div>Test <p>2</p></div>
            <p>Test <span>3</span></p>
        </body>
    </html>
");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/p");

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $node = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $node->appendXML('<h1>This is a test</h1>');

    if ($element->nextSibling) {
        $element->parentNode->insertBefore($node, $element->nextSibling);
    } else {
        $element->parentNode->appendChild($node);
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();

?>
```

And the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Test 1</p><h1>This is a test</h1>
        <div>Test <p>2</p></div>
        <p>Test <span>3</span>t</p><h1>This is a test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this actually answer the question?

Comment: @KennethK.: Well, yes. That's sort of why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: When I do a count of something, I get a number, not HTML :\

Comment: @KennethK.: The question isn't about counting. It's about only modifying the top-level paragraphs, which is what that XPath query matches.

Comment: Thanks Blender. I'm trying to test your answer. Inside the for loop, I just need to add the "test text" *after* the second paragraph. Does xpath make that easier than doing a count?

Comment: @RegEdit: How would you do it with regex? Count the opening and closing `<p>` tags with a loop and insert the HTML after the latter? You might be able to write a monstrous regex, but have fun editing it when it won't work for a corner case. PHP's built-in DOM manipulation functions aren't very clean (unlike [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), which should make this much shorter), but they're cleaner than a regex. See my updated example.